# how can connect Adobe flex server in working flex application using Adobe Flash Builder 4.5?

Tags: flash-builder4.5

I am working on a flex application using adobe flash builder 4.5.

In my application I can connect to the local service using flex server.
How can I connect to the flex server in adobe flash builder 4.5?

Please suggest a solution, or send me any pdf or code file

Thanks in advance,
 Narasimha

Comment: Which version of flex server are you using? The ones I know about is PHP, Adobe ColdFusion, and Microsoft ASP.NET servers. or are you trying to connect to a web service?

Comment: hi shaun I  am using  Adobe ColdFusion

Comment: So, you can connect to the local Adobe ColdFusion server, but not another remote Adobe ColdFusion server?

Comment: ok shaun i will try to connect to local server